# Sending an image data over a socket, but it receives of some different format when it reaches server

Tags: iphone, ios, cfnetwork

I am create a NSData file from the image and sending over server using socket.

```
CFWriteStreamWrite(myWriteStream, (const UInt8 *)data, [data length]);
```

But the server receives it in different format. and unable to open file.

Answer (score 3):

What's the type of 'data' in your code snippet?

If it was a (NSData *) object, you should write like:

```
CFWriteStreamWrite(myWriteStream, (const UInt8 *)[data bytes], [data length]);
```

Comment: thank you, i need to send an image NSData to the server, when it sends the image file and open it in server it says file is corrupted. as the null in Mac is converted to ? symbol in windows. plz help

Comment: the null character of the image data is converted to ? at the server side, please help